# Convert datetime with time zone to specific format with it's timzone

Tags: javascript, datetime, time, timezone, momentjs

Convert

`2020-11-15T02:20:00+03:00`

To

`15-11-2020 2:20  (+3:00)` (any format will do, as long the showing the timezone)

`moment` or pure javascript (strictly no jquery)

Update:

`+3:00` is dynamic value. Could be `+4:00` or `+5:00`.

Comment: So what have you tried already?

Comment: `moment('2020-11-15T02:20:00+03:00', 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ').format('hh:mmA Z');` I can get the time but the `Z` value return my local timezone

Comment: Have a look https://codepen.io/vyspiansky/pen/QWNKKpj

Comment: i should state that `(+3:00)` is dynamic value. could be `(+4:00)` or `(+5:00)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your date format has a fixed timezone offset, try to use `moment.parseZone`.

```
const dateString = '2020-11-15T02:20:00+03:00';
const momentDate = moment.parseZone(dateString);

console.log(momentDate.format('DD-MM-YYYY h:mm (Z)'));
// Output: "15-11-2020 2:20 (+03:00)"
```

**Update:**

Use `H` instead of `h`:

```
const momentDate = moment.parseZone('2020-11-15T23:23:00+03:00');

console.log(momentDate.format('DD-MM-YYYY h:mm (Z)'));
// Wrong hour: "15-11-2020 11:23 (+03:00)"

console.log(momentDate.format('DD-MM-YYYY H:mm (Z)'));
// Correct output: "15-11-2020 23:23 (+03:00)"
```

Thanks to @MattJohnson-Pint for correcting the format template.

Demo - https://codepen.io/vyspiansky/pen/OJNRbPN

Comment: Use `H`, not `h`  (unless you also include `a` or `A`)